# nxlog querylist doesn't work as expected

Tags: event-log, nxlog

[nxlog.conf](http://pastebin.com/75n5sdkj)

The above link is to a copy of my nxlog.conf.  I couldn't find any documentation about how to use multiple  blocks within a querylist block, but based on the name I assumed that I would be able to do this.  My ELK server is receiving ALL events right now, not any of the filtered ones.  I wanted to just use one query block but it is limited to 10 select entries.  I can't find any examples of people using more than like 3 select entries.  Has anyone had any luck with more advance nxlog.conf's?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually there is no issue with the XML.  I was viewing old results in my database from when I was testing nxlog.conf with no queries.  My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue with the query xml is. If there is a limitation on the number of select entries, that's coming from the Windows Eventlog API so that cannot be helped.

On the other hand you can use nxlog's native filtering using *drop()*:

```
Query       <QueryList>\
                <Query Id="0">\
                    <Select Path="Security">*</Select>\
                </Query>\
            </QueryList>
Exec if not ($EventID == 1 or $EventID == 2 or ...) drop();
```